# How to add numbers in a string separated by delimiter

Tags: c#

I need to have the numbers a user inputs added. The numbers will come from a single textbox and are separated by a comma. an example of numbers that can be used are 7,9,10,2,18,6.

Here is my code so far

```
    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = inputNumbTextBox.Text;
        char[] delim = { ',' };
        string[] tokens = str.Split(delim);

        if (char.IsDigit(str, 0))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number");
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question? You already have all the numbers in `tokens`.

Comment: Loop over tokens, convert the numbers to ints and add them up. You've already done the hard part.

Answer (score 1):

use `int.TryParse` instead of `char.IsDigit`:

```
int sum = 0;
string[] tokens = str.Split(delim);
foreach(string str in tokens)
{
    int value = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(str, out value))
    {
        sum += value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add an `else` to let the user know that one+ values weren't able to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var text = "7,9,10,2,18,6";
var sum =
    text
        .Split(new [] { ',' })
        .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim()))
        .Sum();
```

I get the result 52.

I would typically go one step further and define a cleaning function like so:

```
Func<string, int?> clean = x =>
{
    var r = (int?)null;
    int v;
    if (int.TryParse(x.Trim(), out v))
    {
        r = v;
    }
    return r;
};
```

Then I could separate out any extract logic needed to validate the input. Now my summing query would look like this:

```
var sum =
    text
        .Split(new [] { ',' })
        .Select(x => clean(x))
        .Where(x => x.HasValue)
        .Sum();
```